# Is writing a python script that loads GIMP in AWS lambda the right way to process images?

Tags: python, image-processing, aws-lambda, gimp

I work with some artists and we've identified a process that we would like to automate and scale up. Is it possible/recommended to put some python script that loads GIMP on a lambda function to accomplish this?

The reason for GIMP is that we have a one-to-one step-by-step recipe to turn the raw image into the finished product using GIMP. Since GIMP has a python scripting interface we thought it would be ideal.

We use Imagick (ImageMagick) in our site, but we'd have to figure out how the GIMP steps translate into Imagick functions.

So far I've tried running GIMP's functions from a python file `python my_scipt.py` but their documentation seems to indicate that this isn't the way to go about it. It seems their 'python interface' is a plugin for GIMP rather than some python library I can include on a python script.

The ideal solution would be a python script I can run on AWS Lambda that includes a library that gives me an interface to GIMP's functions.

Comment: Consider sharing the processing steps as it may be possible to do it relatively simply with Python wand, or `pyvips` or `PIL/Pillow`.

Comment: Mark thank you for your reply. 

The steps are more or less:
- curve bend
- linear burn
- gaussian blur
- changing saturation
- merging layers

Comment: From what I've been reading, GIMP isn't mean to run the way I want it. I've read Wand being thrown around a lot so I might go with that especially if it's easy to set it up on a lambda function

Comment: You could try adding the `wand` tag and editing your question to be a bit more explicit about the processing. There are some very talented, helpful folk around here...

Comment: Thanks, I'll read about it a bit more before posting a question. Have a good day!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems as though you **CAN** run GIMP as a server, yet you [cannot put it in a lambda function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9001783/using-gimp-as-server-on-windows)

As pointed out by @Mark above, [Michael Schumacher here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49658654/how-can-i-run-headless-batch-gimp-on-aws-lambda-function), and [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1128487/i-need-assistance-with-building-gimp-to-run-under-aws-ec2-instance-and-lambda) there are other tools that might be more suited for this.